# PHP Imagick - Postscript delegate failed: No such file or directory

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick

I have a problem with imagick for PHP.

My environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.9 (1ubuntu4.26)

  - with imagick installed via pecl
- Apache 2.4.7
- ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-09-28 Q16
- Ghostscript 9.25

Showing `phpinfo()` tells me that everything is fine - imagemagick is recognized and pdf is listed in supported formats.

In PHP I make the following:

```
//$pdfAbsolutePath is /path/to/MF-NEU-22306.pdf[0]
$im = new \Imagick($pdfAbsolutePath);
```

At this point I get the following error:

```
Postscript delegate failed `/path/to/MF-NEU-22306.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677
[app/controller/web/fax.php:1028] Imagick->readimage('/path/to/MF-NEU-22306.pdf[0]')
```

The file exists at the specified path.

What am I doing wrong? Calling `convert` from command line manually runs perfect, same as running `gs` from command line. In the output of `phpinfo()` the versions provided for imagick compiled with and ImageMagick library are the same. I also tried to completely uninstall ImageMagick and ghostscript and reinstall it - both from apt-get and compiling from source, but nothing works.

How can I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

In `delegates.xml` in `/etc/ImageMagick/` are thes two lines for pdf delegates:

```
<delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command="&quot;gs&quot; -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 &quot;-sDEVICE=nodevice&quot; &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; &quot;-f%i&quot;"/>
<delegate decode="pdf" encode="ps" mode="bi" command="&quot;gs&quot; -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 &quot;-sDEVICE=nodevice&quot; &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; &quot;-f%i&quot;"/>
```

Edit 2:

I now tried a "workaround" - isntead of specifying the pagenumber in square brackets, I use `$im->setIteratorIndex($i)` while iterating through the pages. It worked so far, but now I have antoher exception:

```
WriteBlob Failed `/path/to/1-607405443.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1726
[app/controller/web/fax.php:1044] Imagick->writeimage('/path/to/1-607405443.png')
```

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Most probably the Ghostscritp executable is not in $PATH for your PHP 'user', so it can't be found to be executed. See this question, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455985/issue-with-imagick-and-also-with-phmagick-postscript-delegate-failed-no-such

Comment: Try looking in your `delegates.xml` file and maybe add the full path to `gs` under the `PDF` delegate.

Comment: Not sure how you are supposed to find the `delegates.xml`, but this works `convert -debug all xc:black info: 2>&1 | grep "Loading delegate"`

Comment: @KenS: I have found this answer to, but my gs is already located under /usr/bin/.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Running your command `convert -debug all...` shows nothing. Running it without grep shows very much, but as expected there is no "Loading delegates".
There is a `delegates.xml` in `/etc/ImageMagick/` - you can see the delegates for pdf in my initial post (too long for comment).

Comment: Try `grep "pdf.*gs" /etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml` and see if you have the full path to `gs` or just `&quot;gs&quot;`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I have added full path of gs (`/usr/bin/gs`) to both pdf delegates, but I still get the same error. I also tried to restart apache without effect.

Comment: I guess it had to do with the specified pagenumber in square brackets, but using `setIteratorIndex()` produced a new error - see my second edit in my initial post.

Comment: If your path is being sent directly to Ghostscript, then adding square brackets to the filename isn't going to work, no. That's not how you specify a desired page to Ghostscript, for that you need -dFirstPage and -dLastPage. Your latest problem doesn't sound like its Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault was a missing tesseract installation on the server... maybe this will help somebody.