# Imagemagick error when trying to load file

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I am trying to create a jpg preview of a pdf file as outlined in this question: [How do I convert a PDF document to a preview image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)

The relevant code to do so is:

```
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
```

I am running this on my localhost on a pdf file but get the error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Imagick::__construct(): HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request '`

The error is being triggered here:

`$im = new imagick(build_url('uploads/files/'.$file_data['file_name'].'[0]'));`

This is the same as the first line in the example code above, and I am providing the full url path to the pdf file, when I echo that it provides the correct path

```
http://oursite.localhost:8888/uploads/files/file_name.pdf[0]
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error? Thank you!

Comment: If you use a relative path? `'./uploads/file/'.$file_data['file_name'].'[0]'`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...getting "no such file or directory" when I try that.  However, I just discovered this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783216/convert-postscript-delegate-failed so I'm going to try that

Comment: first of all your telling imagick to load it from a URL... not the local filesystem... the URL you are requesting is getting an HTTP error from apache saying bad request most likely becuase [0] is not liked with mod security... get rid of the build_url

Comment: Show your function `build_url()` it seems to build a wrong url

Comment: `build_url()` creates our urls and it works correctly. When I echo `build_url('uploads/files/'.$file_data['file_name'].'[0]');` I get `http://oursite.localhost:8888/uploads/files/file_name.pdf[0]`

Comment: @Dan you missed the point... you are telling imagemagick to not load from the local filesystem and rather a URL... and the URL it is requesting... is getting a 400 bad request error... this means pasting  http://oursite.localhost:8888/uploads/files/file_name.pdf[0] into a browser should cause a 400 bad request error

Comment: When I use relative path I still get an error, I get "no such file or directory" error

Comment: @dan what happens in your browser if you go to http://oursite.localhost:8888/uploads/files/file_name.pdf[0] ?

Comment: @dan of course you will get 'no such file or directory' if it includes the http:// in the path name. We will need to see the file structure to even help period

Comment: I noticed that with imagick readimage function the suffix [0] creates fatal error in some pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageMagick is quite bad as HTTP client. Pull down your image first, then feed it into ImageMagick as blob

Use following:

```
 $image = file_get_contents(build_url('uploads/files/'.$file_data['file_name'].'[0]'));
 if ($image !== false)
   {
     $im = new imagick();
     $im->readImageBlob($image);
   }
 else
   {
     echo "Uh-oh... Cannot load image from URL!";
   }
```

Comment: Crank up **error_reporting** - **file_get_contents()** will provide you human readable error message in plain English if something went wrong while pulling the image in